# ASP.NET Automapper using external Configuration Class

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, automapper

I would like to change mimeMessage_MailBox to email_MailBox entity through Automapper the configuration codes goes as below.

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{

    public static void configure() {
        Mapper.CreateMap<mimeMessage_MailBox, email_MailBox>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SenderName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.From.Mailboxes.ToString()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailSubject, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Subject))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailCC, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => string.Join(",",src.Cc.Mailboxes.ToString())))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ReceiverEmail, opt => opt.MapFrom(src=>string.Join(",", src.To.Mailboxes.ToString())))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailBody, opt => opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Body.ContentBase.OriginalString));

    }
```

Now Saving the data to DbContext goes as

```
public void Save(mimeMessage_MailBox mail)
    {
        email_MailBox mailbox = new email_MailBox();
         using (EmailEntityModelContext context = new EmailEntityModelContext())
        {
            context.email_MailBox.Add(Mapper.Map<mimeMessage_MailBox, email_MailBox>(mail, mailbox));
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Do i have to call AutoMapperConfiguration.configure() inside the Save() method? 
Or is there something like DI magic? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mapper.CreateMap()
Mapper.Map()
```

These methods use a static (global) Automapper instance. Thus it's enough to call `CreateMap` once per application lifetime.

FYI: you could create additional mapper instances and control their lifetimes. Read the docs: [Static and Instance API](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Static-and-Instance-API).

Comment: I tried to check out IoC like https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/05/12/automapper-and-ioc/ so that i could load the

Comment: @Marks, what is the problem you are trying to resolve with Ioc?